# winston + PM2 logging uncaughtException twice

Tags: node.js, logging, pm2, winston

I am using [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/) for my NodeJS apps, to have a structured logging format (JSON) that later I will process and send to Logstash via Filebeat.

As suggested by PM2 and [12factor.net](https://12factor.net/logs) I'm logging using `winston.transports.Console` transport and letting PM2 to handle the `stdout`and `stderr` in my `ecosystem.json`.

In my `logger.js` module I have the following:

```
"use strict";
const winston = require("winston");
// Remove logging on console
winston.remove(winston.transports.Console);
// env
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const isDev = env === "development";
// The default Console transport
const defaultLogLevel = isDev ? "debug" : "info";

const consoleTransport = new winston.transports.Console({
    level: defaultLogLevel,
    colorize: true,
    json: true,
    timestamp: true,
    exceptionsLevel: "error",
    prettyPrint: false,
    handleExceptions: true,
    humanReadableUnhandledException: false,
    exitOnError: true
});

const defaultOptions = {
    transports: [
    consoleTransport
    ]
};


module.exports = function(options)
{
    let initOpts = defaultOptions;
    if(options)
    {
        Object.assign(initOpts, options);
    }
    const logger = new winston.Logger(initOpts);
    // suppress any logger errors
    logger.emitErrs = false;
    winston.handleExceptions(consoleTransport);

    return logger;
};
```

In my main app file `server.js` I run this code to simulate an unhandled Exception being thrown, a fake dependency is being required and not found:

```
"use strict";
var log         = require('./logger')({name: "api-messages"});
log.info("some info message");
log.error("some error message");
var notFound = require("someInexistentPackage");
```

Finally, in my PM2 `ecosystem.json` I have the following:

```
{
  "apps":
  [
    {
      "name"            : "my-app",
      "script"          : "server.js",
      "max_restarts"    : 1,
      "error_file"      : "~/.pm2/logs/my-app.log",
      "out_file"        : "~/.pm2/logs/my-app.log",
      "merge_logs"      : true

    }
  ]
}
```

When I run `pm2 start ecosystem.json` the contents of the log files are the following:

```
{
  "level": "info",
  "message": "some info message",
  "timestamp": "2017-06-08T16:10:05.967Z"
}
{
  "level": "error",
  "message": "some error message",
  "timestamp": "2017-06-08T16:10:05.968Z"
}
Error: Cannot find module 'someInexistentPackage'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mps/Sites/my-app/server.js:10:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
{
  "date": "Thu Jun 08 2017 13:10:05 GMT-0300 (-03)",
  "process": {
    "pid": 50862,
    "uid": 501,
    "gid": 20,
    "cwd": "/Users/mps/Sites/my-app",
    "execPath": "/Users/mps/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/node",
    "version": "v7.10.0",
    "argv": [
      "/Users/mps/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/node",
      "/Users/mps/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js"
    ],
    "memoryUsage": {
      "rss": 36724736,
      "heapTotal": 9879552,
      "heapUsed": 6309680,
      "external": 63983
    }
  },
  "os": {
    "loadavg": [
      2.49560546875,
      2.228515625,
      2.0205078125
    ],
    "uptime": 329559
  },
  "trace": [
    {
      "column": 15,
      "file": "module.js",
      "function": "Module._resolveFilename",
      "line": 470,
      "method": "_resolveFilename",
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 25,
      "file": "module.js",
      "function": "Module._load",
      "line": 418,
      "method": "_load",
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 17,
      "file": "module.js",
      "function": "Module.require",
      "line": 498,
      "method": "require",
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 19,
      "file": "internal/module.js",
      "function": "require",
      "line": 20,
      "method": null,
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 20,
      "file": "/Users/mps/Sites/my-app/server.js",
      "function": null,
      "line": 10,
      "method": null,
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 32,
      "file": "module.js",
      "function": "Module._compile",
      "line": 571,
      "method": "_compile",
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 10,
      "file": "module.js",
      "function": "Module._extensions..js",
      "line": 580,
      "method": ".js",
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 32,
      "file": "module.js",
      "function": "Module.load",
      "line": 488,
      "method": "load",
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 12,
      "file": "module.js",
      "function": "tryModuleLoad",
      "line": 447,
      "method": null,
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 3,
      "file": "module.js",
      "function": "Module._load",
      "line": 439,
      "method": "_load",
      "native": false
    }
  ],
  "stack": [
    "Error: Cannot find module 'someInexistentPackage'",
    "    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)",
    "    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)",
    "    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mps/Sites/my-app/server.js:10:20)",
    "    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)",
    "    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)",
    "    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)"
  ],
  "level": "error",
  "message": "uncaughtException: Cannot find module 'someInexistentPackage'",
  "timestamp": "2017-06-08T16:10:05.972Z"
}
```

As you can see, PM2 is adding the uncaught Exception to the log file, i.e. this code:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'someInexistentPackage'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mps/Sites/my-app/server.js:10:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

This breaks the format/structure of my logs, since it's plain text instead of the formatted JSON I receive from `winston`.

I'm confident this is a PM2 issue/misconfiguration, because if I run `node server.js` the console output are just the JSON objects.

Do I have to setup a specific property in PM2 `ecosystem.json` file?

How can I tell PM2 to ignore Node's `uncaughtException`?

The only alternative I have come up with (which I haven't tried yet), is to change my winston transport to `winston.transports.File`, redirect **ALL** logs to `stdout`and tell PM2 to save `stderr` in a different file, but I'd rather stick with the console aproach.

Comment: Not sure if you can get PM2 to ignore those exceptions, but it does have an option to output JSON itself: `--log-type json`

Comment: @robertklep that would print the "plain text" exception as JSON indeed, but I'm still missing all my winston specific formatting (properties), also I'd have duplicate exceptions being logged.

Comment: You can also add a custom [`uncaughtException`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) handler in your code to prevent the stack trace from being written to stderr, and emit a log message instead.

Comment: @robertklep I already tried using an `uncaughtException` event handler, PM2 still adds the exception to the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to prevent PM2 from logging the `uncaughtException` is to pass `--no-pmx` as a flag, i.e. `pm2 start --no-pmx myapp.js` or to add `pmx: false` to the `ecosystem.json` file.

This disables PMX injection into PM2, which is the responsible for logging this `uncaughtException`.