# Pm2 Not Providing Logs With Ecosystem + startOrRestart

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, pm2, winston

I'm currently running a node application with Pm2, but am struggling to get logs.

Currently, if I start the script with just `node index.js` my logger function (using `winston`) sends the logs to the screen just fine. The first two lines in the below video ("IS THIS SHOWING UP" and "YA") are from `console.log` statements inside my javascript files, and the latter lines are from my logger function. It looks like this:

[image]

However, in the deployment of my server, I'm using an `ecosystem.config.js` file with Pm2. When I run my server with `pm2 start index.js`, the logger also works. HOWEVER, when I start my server using my ecosystem file, the pm2 instance only sends the `console.log` statements to the output, not the logs output by the `winston` logger.

This means that I've got something misconfigured in my ecosystem.config.js file. What's going wrong?

package.json (script that kicks off the pm2 instance)

```
  {
   "name": "graphqlCourse",
    ...
    "scripts": {
      "prod:serve": "NODE_ENV=production pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.config.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
     ...
```

ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    /// I believe that something is misconfigured in here relating to logging.....
    {
      name: process.env.APP_NAME,
      args: ["--color"],
      interpreter: process.env.NODE_PATH,
      cwd: path.resolve(process.env.PROJECT_PATH, 'current' ),
      script: 'dist/index.js',
      instances: process.env.INSTANCES || 0,
      exec_mode: "cluster",
      env: {
        ...process.env,
      },
    },
  ],
  deploy: {
    production: {
      user: "harrison",
      host: process.env.HOST,
      key: "~/.ssh/id_rsa2",
      ref: "origin/master",
      repo: process.env.GIT_REPO,
      path: process.env.PROJECT_PATH,
      "pre-deploy-local": `scp -Cr envs harrison@${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PROJECT_PATH}/current`,
      "post-deploy": `yarn install --ignore-engines && \
         pwd && \
         yarn prod:build && \
         yarn prod:serve`,
    },
  },
};
```

-- EDIT --

Here's my logger as well:

```
import winston, { format } from "winston";
import "winston-daily-rotate-file"; // Attaches new transport to winston.transports

// Define the custom settings for each transport (file, console)
let consoleOptions = {
  level: "info",
  handleExceptions: true,
  stderrLevels: ["error"],
  silent: process.env.SILENT === "true",
  format: format.combine(
    format.colorize(),
    format.align(),
    format.printf((info) => {
      const { level, message } = info;
      return `[${level}]: ${message}`;
    })
  ),
};

let consoleTransport = new winston.transports.Console(consoleOptions);

// Log rotation
const transport = new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
  filename: `API_${process.env.NODE_ENV}.log`,
  dirname: `./${
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "dist" : "server"
  }/logs`,
  frequency: null, // Rely on date pattern, rotate daily
  datePattern: "YYYY-MM-DD",
  zippedArchive: true,
  maxSize: "10m",
  maxFiles: "14d",
  format: format.combine(format.timestamp(), format.json()),
});

transport.on("rotate", (oldFileName, newFilename) => {
  console.log(`ROTATING LOGS. OLD: ${oldFileName}  -- NEW: ${newFilename}`);
});

// Handles input from Morgan.
var writer = new winston.createLogger({
  transports: [transport],
});

// Handles logger.XX calls from within app.
export const logger = new winston.createLogger({
  transports: [consoleTransport, transport],
  exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
});

// Recieves message from morganToWinston
logger.stream = {
  write: function (message) {
    writer.info(message);
  },
};
```

Comment: Hi @Harry, did you try using merge_logs: true

Comment: No luck! Still just getting the console.log() statements when I try running my prod:serve command, instead of the logging as well.

Comment: You can check here as well. I think they were able to create logs twice..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441017/winston-pm2-logging-uncaughtexception-twice